# How to init Javascript object with data from Jinja2 template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I'm working on a Flask app where some data gets passed to a template, and I want to make that data available to multiple instances of an object. Here's what it would look like if I just hardcoded the desired data into my .js file:

```js
var Module = function(selector) {
    var targetDiv = selector,
    targetData = 'lorem ipsum sit dolor',
      
    show = function() {
        $('<p>' + targetData + '</p>').appendTo(targetDiv);
    };
  
    return {
        show: show,
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    firstModule = new Module($('#first'));
    secondModule = new Module($('#second'));
  
    firstModule.show();
    secondModule.show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='first'></div>
<div id='second'></div>
```

I can't just call a function on an unconstructed Module object, so my next step is to create a static-like `ModuleFactory` that I can load with data from jinja, and then create Modules from there:

```
var ModuleFactory = function() {
    var targetData = null,

    setData = function(data) {
        targetData = data;
    },

    create = function(selector) {
        return new Module(selector, data);
    };

    return {
        setData: setData,
        create: create,
    };
} ();
```

Then I attempt to call `ModuleFactory.setData({{data}});` from a `<script>` tag in the HTML, and do something like `ModuleFactory.create($('#first')).show();` in the .js

But of course because I have to include my .js file before using the ModuleFactory in the HTML, I end up constructing the objects before the factory is initialized.

(Past this point, my workaround attempts stop being relevant to the problem.)

Anyway, what's the correct way of getting data from Jinja to my JS module? There has to be a common pattern or something.

Answer (score 0):

This feels awful, but it works:

Have an object with a `runProgram` method, which takes the desired data as a parameter, then executes the logic that had previously been inside the document ready function. e.g.

```
var ProgramRunner = function() {
    var runProgram = function(data) {
        ModuleFactory.setData(data);
        firstModule = ModuleFactory.create($('#first'));
        firstModule.show();
    };
    return {
        runProgram: runProgram;
    };
};
```

Then just

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { ProgramRunner.runProgram({{data}}) });    
</script>
```

in the HTML.

(Leaving question open, because I suspect there's a much better way of handling this.)